# weird behaviour of mysql after running mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have different ubuntu servers running mysql 8.
After installing the server I use to secure the installation with the same settings for all the servers.
First of all I disable the possibility for root to login remotely. After this change the command:

```
sudo mysql
```

will make me login with root user from the server shell while running

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

will keep me out and this is the expected behaviour.

On one server I run mysql_secure_installation with the usual procedure and everything worked as expected but:

```
sudo mysql
```

will keep me out with the message:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

while

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

will log me in normally (exactly the opposite of what I expect to be)

Where should I look for to solve this? Did anyone face the same issue before?

Comment: Your 'sudo mysql' is translated at 'run as root' the command 'mysql'. As you noted earlier you need 'mysql -u root -p' to login as root.  You are good to go with 'mysql -u root -p ' as you are logged in as root.  I am not sure why you need to run the mysql cli as root but you are free to do so but you still need to provide a password - 'sudo mysql -p'.

Comment: First of all mysql-u root -p is not the same of sudo mysql in terms of security. Sudo mysql works only from the shell, the other can be used also in scripts. Then, for the reasons why you need to access as root: root should be the only one with grant rights and thus the only one able to create or modify a user. If you create users with grant rights it’s the same as a root user for security. I’d suggest you to dig more the security aspects of MySQL